# Choosing a partition key and the right index for Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a list of 4 million companies each in its own json file. I'm planning to store this data in Azure because I need to make queries on the company name and it needs to find results in less than a second. First I tried SQL Server but it's slow, so I want to give Cosmos DB a try even though I'm a complete beginner here.
If I want fast searches on the name property does this mean that it has to be the partition key? There are only a few companies with the same name, so I'll have millions of logical partitions, does this make sense? Or can I use the industry code as a partition and also make an index for the name? If I can have another index besides the partition, how can I create it so that it is appropriate for string searches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, this question may get closed as asking for opinion. Will answer as this is a frequently asked question.

The answer to any question like this is, it depends. It's important to understand the concept of partition, which is a server that stores and provides access to your data, versus an index, which is used by queries to find your data within a partition.

Company name may be fine as a partition key it doesn't have to be. The key here is to know that queries that span logical partitions get progressively slower and more expensive the larger the container is. A partition key defines how a container will scale out. If you have a small container that is less than 50GB in size and < 10K RU/s, queries without the partition key perform the same as queries that use the partition key.

You can have an infinite number of logical partitions. Containers with a logical partition per item is functionally a key-value store where you can use ReadItemAsync() to quickly get items vs a query which is slower.

While cross partition queries are not ideal for large containers, they don't need to be avoided entirely. Apply the pareto principle when designing. If you answer 80% of your queries using industry code, then use that. If you use company name, use that instead. If you do both in equal measure and at sufficient volumes, you could consider creating a materialized view of your data using change feed to copy the data into a second container with a different partition key to serve queries with different partition key.

For anyone new to Cosmos DB I recommend learning about data modeling and partitioning concepts. Knowing these concepts ahead of time can save you lots of time and effort. Here is a list of links on this [Gist on Cosmos DB data modeling and partitioning](https://gist.github.com/markjbrown/114179b3d530abe0eaa25fb9ac54b609)

Comment: thank you Mark for the nice explanation and the resources you shared! I used the "name" as the partition key and so far the performance is good, but only 10% of the data is inserted. I excluded everything from indexing because I understood this will make insertions faster. I'll include the /name/? path when all the data is in Cosmos DB and then I'll try to query again.

Answer (score 1):

there are many questions in this "one" question, but yeah, having item name as a partition key is a bad idea in case, but it usually is a bad idea anyway. industry code as a partition makes a lot more sense.
alternatively you can create synthetic partition keys (like batch all companies in europe\us\arbitrary region by industry code or use first letter + industry code, etc)

you can have index for name (or any property really) and by default all fields are indexed, so no changes required

Comment: so there's nothing else that needs to be done for the name field? in SQL Server for example I had to create a FULL TEXT SEARCH index instead of a regular index, I was thinking that maybe Cosmos DB has something similar

Comment: no, its the default